# Number of possible outcomes when rolling indistinguishable dice?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, dice

So I know the answer is

$$N(n) = \frac{( n + 5 )!}{ n! \cdot 5! }$$

where $n$ is the number of dice.

but I'm not able to prove it either mathematically or intuitively,
although I'm able to verify for various cases.

I tried to prove it by first assuming the dice are different, and then eliminating duplicates but that method doesn't look very promising.

How do I prove the above result.

Comment: Note that these outcomes are not equally likely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each outcome can be represented as a tuple of $6$ nonnegative numbers indicating how many times each side appeared (the numbers must sum to $n$). For instance, $(1,3,2,0,1,0)$ represents a roll of seven dice where "1" appears once, "2" appears three times, "3" appears two times, "4" appears zero times, "5" appears once, and "6" appears zero times.

You can count this using the [stars-and-bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two): there are $\binom{n+5}{5}$ ways to arrange $5$ bars and $n$ stars in a row.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n_1,\cdots,n_6$ be respectively the numbers of dice showing up $1,\dots,6$. We are looking for the  number of non-negative solutions to the equation : $$n_1+\cdots+n_6=n.$$
Using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) it is:
$$
\binom {n+6-1}{6-1}.
$$